# Jhipster get user oauth

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jhipster

I am newer with jhipster and spring security.

I have created a new application with OAtuh 2.0. It's work well.

Now, in my code, I wish get the user oauth. Do you understand ?

As  : MyUserConnected = oauth.getUserInfo();

Thank you

Vince

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are looking for the current User's infos, the one who's currently connected :

```
final String userLogin = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin();
```

will get you, by definition, the current user login, then :

```
Optional<User> currentUser = userRepository.findOneByLogin(userLogin);
```

will get you the entity User linked to the login, from which you can access all information with `currentUser.get().getEmail()` for example.

I don't think it's different, whether it's OAuth or not.

hope this helps.